# PrimeFaces invalidated component is not rerendered

Tags: ajax, primefaces, rerender

PrimeFaces 6.1.
I have a SelectOneListBox with letters. Upon change, ajax event is triggered and fills PickList with words starting with selected letter. The PickList is valid if it contains the word XX, where X is the selected letter.

If the PickList is valid, everything works fine. If it gets invalidated, everything works fine (ajax is fired, messages are rerendered, etc.), only the PickList is not refreshed upon letters change, unless it is valid again.

Is there a way how to rerender the PickList, even if it not valid?

The code: Web.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectOneListbox value="#{Web.letter}" required="true">
                <f:selectItems value="#{Web.letters}" var="letter"
                    itemValue="#{letter}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" update="words"
                    listener="#{Web.letterChanged}" />
            </p:selectOneListbox>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="words">
                <p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{Web.words}" var="word"
                    itemLabel="#{word}" itemValue="#{word}"
                    validator="#{Web.validateWords}" showSourceFilter="true"
                    filterMatchMode="startsWith" showTargetControls="true">
                    <p:ajax event="reorder" update="pickListMessages" />
                    <p:ajax event="transfer" update="pickListMessages" />
                </p:pickList>
                <p:message id="pickListMessages" for="pickList" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Web.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

import org.primefaces.model.DualListModel;

@ManagedBean (name = "Web")
@ViewScoped
@SuppressWarnings (
{ "javadoc", "nls", "unused" })
public class WebBean implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4067529596686991391L;

  private Set<String> letters = new TreeSet<> (Arrays.asList ("A", "B", "C"));

  private String letter = "A";

  private DualListModel<String> words = new DualListModel<> (new ArrayList<> (),
    new ArrayList<> ());

  public Set<String> getLetters ()
  {
    return letters;
  }

  public String getLetter ()
  {
    return letter;
  }

  public void setLetter (String letter)
  {
    this.letter = letter;
  }

  public DualListModel<String> getWords ()
  {
    return words;
  }

  public void setWords (DualListModel<String> words)
  {
    this.words = words;
  }

  private void refreshWordsList ()
  {
    List<String> source = words.getSource ();
    source.clear ();
    source.addAll (Arrays.asList (letter + 'A', letter + 'B', letter + 'C'));
    words.getTarget ().clear ();
  }

  public void letterChanged (AjaxBehaviorEvent ajaxEvent)
  {
    refreshWordsList ();
  }

  public void validateWords (FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component,
    Object value) throws ValidatorException
  {
    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    DualListModel<String> dualListModel = (DualListModel<String>) value;
    List<String> validatedWords = dualListModel.getTarget ();
    for (String word : validatedWords)
    {
      // OK?
      if (word.charAt (0) == word.charAt (1))
      {
        return;
      }
    }
    throw new ValidatorException (
      new FacesMessage (FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "No double", null));
  }
}
```